# Dimension of an equipotential surface

Tags: electrostatics, differential-geometry, potential, spacetime-dimensions

How many dimensions has an [equipotential surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipotential_surface)?

My book says it has $3$ dimensions but I think it has $2$ dimensions because a plane is an object of dimension $2$ as well. From linear algebra, I know that the dimension of a vector space is the amount of vectors in a spanning, linear independent set, but I cannot apply this definition to this case as an equipotential surface is not a vector space. How would I know what the dimension is?

Comment: Which book is this?

Comment: It was not really a book, but an online exercise related to the book "Physics for scientists & engineers with modern physics" by Douglas Giancoli.

Comment: You are correct. The potential is defined as a space function, $\phi(\vec x)$. The condition $\phi(\vec x) = a$ with some real number $a$ limits this to a two dimensional surface within three dimensional space. Perhaps the third dimension is meant such that this surface is not a plane, but something more complicated. So it is embedded into three dimensional space. Or one interprets the potential as $\phi(\vec x, t)$; then the surfaces would be three dimensional in space-time.

Comment: With just the information that you have given, I have to conclude that there's a typo in the book.  Surely Giancoli knows better.

Comment: @garyp It could very well be that the typo is from an editor or a minion who went through the n'th edition for the author when it was converted to "online" format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An equipotential surface (any surface, really) is a '2-manifold', i.e. a continuous two-way mapping, at every
locality, of a 2-dimensional (plane) patch.   The equipotential surface may
be a sphere, or torus, or other shape that cannot exist on the plane, however:
those shapes have three-dimensional character due to their global
connections, while having two-dimensional character near each point.

One wouldn't describe a sphere surface as 'two-dimensional' because
it cannot exist in a plane, nor describe that surface as 'three-dimensional' because its local patches are two-dimensional.

It is possible to do some very slick tricks with conformal mapping, using
the differential equations of fields and applying them to differentiable
manifolds.

Comment: What? A two-dimensional manifold is exactly what 2-manifold means.

Comment: Oh, sure: if its a MANIFOLD that's OK; but if you're talking about the surface of  a sphere, and say 'it's two-dimensional', there will be  confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct and your "book" is in error.  The points of a surface must satisfy one equation so $3$ dimensions of ambient space - $1$ constraint = $2$ remaining dimension for your surface.

You can always define a "local" [normal vector](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) to your surface and thus locally your surface will look like a 2d plane perpendicular to this normal.